# SQL multiple records

Tags: sql, join

I have source table as shown below:

```
ID  Status  State_id
X   Active  1
X   Active  2
X   Active  3
X   Active  4
Y   Active  2
Y   Active  3
Z   Active  1
Z   Active  2
Z   Active  3
A   Active  2
A   Active  3
```

I need 2 output based on State_id 2,3.

Set 1 for having only 2,3 state_id

```
ID  Status
Y   Active
A   Active
```

Set 2 for having additional state id with 2,3

```
ID  Status
X   Active
Z   Active
```

Comment: `SELECT ID, Status From tbl WHERE state_id IN (2,3) AND ID in ('Y','A')` Which database do you use? What is the difference between Set 1 and Set 2? Is it the number of active entries?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  /*Set 1*/
  select t1.id, t1.status
  from table1 t1
  where t1.state_id in (2, 3) /*ids you want */
  and t1.id not in ((
    select distinct t2.id
    from table1 t2
    where t2.state_id in (1, 4) /*ids you dont want*/
  ))
  group by t1.id, t1.status
```

Just flip the IDs to get set 2

Answer (score 1):

You can use this scripts.

**Set 1**

```
SELECT 
    ID, Status
FROM 
    @Tbl T 
GROUP BY 
    ID, Status
HAVING
    SUM(CASE WHEN State_id IN (2,3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 2
    AND SUM(CASE WHEN State_id IN (2,3) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) = 0
```

Result:

```
ID   Status
---- ----------
A    Active
Y    Active
```

**Set 2**

```
SELECT 
    ID, Status
FROM 
    @Tbl T 
GROUP BY 
    ID, Status
HAVING
    SUM(CASE WHEN State_id IN (2,3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 2
    AND SUM(CASE WHEN State_id IN (2,3) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) > 0
```

Result:

```
ID   Status
---- ----------
X    Active
Z    Active
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should give you expected result.

**Updated**
[SqlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/5bda0/9)

```
--Set 1 
SELECT id ,status
FROM table1 
-- WHERE status='Active' 
GROUP BY id ,status
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT state_id) =count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN state_id IN (2,3) THEN state_id END) ;

 --Set2 
SELECT id ,status
FROM table1 
GROUP BY id ,status
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT state_id)>count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN state_id IN (2,3) 
  THEN state_id END) 
AND COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN state_id IN (2,3) THEN state_id END) =2;
```